# Cognos Framework Removed Field Preventing Validation

Tags: cognos-bi

I am attempting to fix a cognos framework package which has not been working due to a field it was referencing no longer being available in the data. The reson for this was the field had been renamed.

I have update the fields in the foundation and presentation layers and re-built the relationships which use the expired field but when trying to validate the package it shows an error saying that it is still using the field which doesn't exist.

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard. I think this was a cacheing issue. I have had the server this is on restarted and the issue has resolved itself.